# How to update input values having same "name" but different "values". React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nested-object

> I have a nested object and I have to update the state using single
> onChange, But I'm changing based on names so it updates all the fields
> having same name. Please let me know how to update such state.

````
   the_data: {
    key: {
      nested_key1: {
        value_to_be_changed: 1,
        value_to_be_changed: 1
      },
      nested_key2: {
        value_to_be_changed: 1,
        value_to_be_changed: 50
      }
    },
    key: {
      value: 1,
      value: 80,
      value: 2.0,
    },
    key: {
      value: 1,
      value: 80,
      value: 2.0,
    },
  },
}```

This is how I'm updating state right now  but it doesn't work.
 
    if (Object.keys(data.body.key.nested_key1).includes(name)) {
      updateData2((oldVal) => {
        const newVal = { ...oldVal }
        type T = keyof typeof newVal.body.key.nested_key1.;
        let name: T = e.target.name;
        newVal.body.key.value_to_be_changed[name] = value;
        return newVal;
      })
    }
````

Comment: Why do you have multiple object properties with the same naming hierarchy? If possible, can you post your actual use-case? I'd also suggest a different structure for your state, and avoiding synthetic events with your input change handler. More than likely there's a way to isolate the state you're trying to change. Deeply nested state is typically best avoided as it complicates diffing.

Comment: I'll have to keep the schema structure as it is and it is deeply nested having keys with same names.

Comment: No object should ever have identical key names without a differentiating parent key name. Are you instead perhaps needing an array? Or I may be misunderstanding the problem. What is the data you're working with. A list of different accounts and their attributes? Need more details.

Comment: @warrenbuffering yes the parent key names are different.